# Give a geometric interpretation of the linear maps defined by the following matrices:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**I have this exercise, and I don't get what is geometric interpretation of the linear maps. Could someone clarify this?**

Give a geometric interpretation of the linear maps defined by the following matrices:

A=$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$
B=$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$
C=$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Try with some simple vector to see how those are transfomed, that is

- $e_1=(1,0,0),e_2=(0,1,0), e_3=(0,0,1)$ for $A$ and $B$

and

- $e_1=(1,0),e_2=(0,1)$ for $C$

Comment: It would be good to clarify: you are not just using "simple vectors", but rather the basis vectors of the Cartesian coordinate system. To the OP: if you find out how these basis vectors are transformed, then you can easily transform any vector, or consequently any geometric shape

Comment: @YuriyS You are completely right, that's a correct and useful clarification! Thanks